# How to enable progress bar during postinstall in innosetup?

Tags: inno-setup

Im making a game repack using ISDone.Created two checkboxes for Directx and Vc++. the installation progressbar went fine for ssInstall section but progressbar not showing for ssPostinstall  section !

here is my sample code

```
if CurStep=ssPostInstall then begin
if DirectXCB.Checked then begin
  Status.Caption:='Installing DirectX';
  Exec2(ExpandConstant('{src}\Redist\DirectX\Dx.cmd'),'/silent',false);
end;
if VisualCCB.Checked then begin
  Status.Caption:='Installing Visual C++';
  Exec2(ExpandConstant('{src}\Redist\vcredist_x86.exe'),'/silent',false);
end;
end;

 if (CurStep=ssInstall) and ISDoneError then begin
Exec2(ExpandConstant('{uninstallexe}'), '/VERYSILENT', false);


end;
end;
```

Pls suggest any ideas !

Comment: I'm asking everyone who posts question about `ISDone`. Where did you get that ? Is there any official site for this library ? Could you edit your question and include the link to that site, please ?

Comment: refer freearc.org for ISDone example scripts !

Comment: I don't need examples, I need the official site where I can read about and download the `ISDone` itself.

Comment: did u knew russian ! then refer [link](krinkels.org) (fileforums.com).

Comment: It's a library made by crackers (note "game repack").  Avoid helping.